# The instance of entity type 'IdentityUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using aspnet core Identity to handle users, I am trying to update the password with the method ResetPasswordAsync() but I get the error message

The instance of entity type 'CustomUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.

CustomUser being a class that inherit from IdentityUser

The reason of this error is probably because I am querying for the user before I update it, but I don't know what the problem is since I am using AsNoTracking(). So I believe the problem might be something more related to the IdentityUser class.

here is the code:

```
public async Task<bool> UpdatePassword(int userId, string token, string password)
{
     var user = await _context.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);
     var results = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, password);
     return true;
}
```

code that is called before this one:

```
public async Task<bool> SendForgetPasswordEmail(string username) {
    var user = await _context.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == userName);
    var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
    var mailServiceVars = _configuration.GetSection("MailService");
    var usernameMail = mailServiceVars["Username"];
    var passwordMail = mailServiceVars["Password"];
    var mailService = new MailService("smtp.gmail.com", usernameMail, passwordMail);

    mailService.SendEmail(
        username,
        "Recover your Password",
        string.Concat("https://localhost:44374/resetPassword?token=", token),
        string.Empty
        );
    return true;
}
```

_context is a dbContext that inherits Entity's IdentityDbContext class.

_userManager is a UserManager class from AspNetCore.Identity library.

_contex, _configuration and _userManager are initialized through dependency injection.

The Users table that I am accessing with _context was created with Identity library.

please let me know if you have any more questions or if you need more. This is a simplified version of my code.

Comment: What happens _before_ this code gets called?

Comment: I'm afraid, the simplified version of your code is not enough to determine what's wrong with it.

Comment: If possible, kindly provide more information regarding the said issue as the above mention information is not giving any idea regarding the cause of the issue. Make sure the table's id column is set as an Identity column.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I found a way to fix it.
Just using _userManager instead of _context here:

```
     var user = await _context.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);
```

so instead the code would be

```
public async Task<bool> UpdatePassword(int userId, string token, string password)
{
     var user = await _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);
     var results = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, password);
     return true;
}
```